# Minify variable/function names in PowerShell source

Tags: powershell, obfuscation, minify

Is there a way/library to minify source code so that it looks like i.e. jquery.min.js? or at least obfuscate it random way. I mean names of vars and functions minified to a,b,c, etc. All minify libraries I found in fact are about removing excessive spaces and line breaks. Thanks!

Comment: You can use a semicolon `;` to remove line-breaks and at most you can remove extra spaces (tabs) to minify your code.

Comment: Can you tell us what your motivation is?

Comment: Mainly I want not to make life easier for guys who will be reversing my source. There's a big difference when you see cute logical names kinda "getUserId( $id )" and "a($b)"